# Setting initial ComboBox currentText to empty string in QML

Tags: combobox, qml

I have a `ComboBox` in *QML* that displays a list from *1* to *10*. I want the `currentText` from the `ComboBox` to be an empty string, so that after I click, I can select another text.

```
ComboBox {
    id: position
    visible: radioBtn.checked && pageModel.locked
    model: root.pageModel.slots
    textRole: "gameid"
    font.pixelSize: scrMgr.size.height * scrMgr.btnRatio[2]
    width: scrMgr.size.width * 0.0729  // 70
    height: textt.height + scrMgr.size.height * 0.01
    anchors.verticalCenter: radioBtn.verticalCenter
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `currentIndex: -1`?

Comment: don't work in this case but for this ComboBox it works

```ComboBox {
                    id: series
                    currentIndex: -1
                    visible: radioBtn.checked && pageModel.locked
                    model: ListModel {
                        ListElement { text: "12345"; }
                        ListElement { text: "6789"; }
                        ListElement { text: "345678"; }
                    }```

Comment: Your code snippet in the question is incomplete and not testable, so I don't know why it doesn't work. If you could post a minimal reproducible example, I can provide a proper solution.